# parsing from colum in perl or bash

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk

a file I am working with looks like this

```
NAMES   n0  n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6  n7
REGION  chr 1   100000
404 AAAAAAGA
992 TTTTTTTA
1146    CCCCGGCC
1727    CCCCCACC
1778    GCCCCCCC
```

would need to split the file based on the number in the column - create a new file for every 1000 units so the output would e be

```
file1
 NAMES  n0  n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6  n7
    REGION  chr 404 992
    404 AAAAAAGA
    992 TTTTTTTA

file2
 NAMES  n0  n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6  n7
     REGION chr 1146    1778
1146 CCCCGGCC
1727 CCCCCACC
1778 GCCCCCCC
```

so split the first colum every 1000 units (first is from 1 to 1000) file 2 is from 1000 to 2000 also the start an end positions would be changed in every file (line starting with REG) as the first number is the number in the first line of the file adn the other number is the number in the last line of hte file. The header needs to be present in all files. Is there a way to name the files from that systematically with file1, file2....? /t is used throughout all files to make space...

i tried

```
awk '
NR==1 {
   h = $0
   k = 1000
   f = "file"k/1000
   print > f
   getline
   print "REGION chr",k-999,k > f
   next
} 
$1 <=k {
   print > f
   next
} 
{
   k=1000*int(1+$1/1000)
   f="file"k/1000
   print h > f
   print "REGION chr",k-999,k > f
   print > f
}' file
```

Comment: would be great if peopel could tell what is wrong with the q?

Comment: This can be done easily using a Perl script. But it would be better if you presented some Perl code first and showed where you got stuck..

Comment: hmm..my perl is very bad I am afraid...so I tried to do in awk...sorr

Comment: I don't see this question as being overly broad. The requirement is well-defined, and the OP has shown his awk code after being prompted

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk 'function print_vals() {
   fn="file" c;
   print hdr > fn;
   print "REGION  chr", sn, en >> fn;
   for (i in a)
      print a[i] >> fn;
} NR == 1 {
   hdr=$0;
   c=0;
   next
} NF==2 && $1 >= 1000*c {
   if (c)
      print_vals();
   delete a;
   i=0;
   c++;
   sn=$1;
} NF==2 {
   a[++i]=$0;
   en=$1;
} END {
   print print_vals();
 }' file
```

**Verification:**

```
cat file1
NAMES   n0  n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6  n7
REGION  chr 404 992
404 AAAAAAGA
992 TTTTTTTA

cat file2
NAMES   n0  n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6  n7
REGION  chr 1146 1778
1146    CCCCGGCC
1727    CCCCCACC
1778    GCCCCCCC
```

Comment: is there a trailin \t at the last line of the NAM lin?..because that would not be good...

Comment: Where did you find a trailing tab?

Comment: @anubhava that is okay for the test set but not for the real data from here https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6ukumbj08cwk99/arg_t1.gz?dl=0 could you maybe hava a look there is somethign with the numeric column not working

Comment: I cannot test with a massive file. Consider making a small sample for which this solution doesn't work. That will be easier for to investigate and make some modifications, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have an `awk` answer, but as this question is tagged `perl` I'll chip in a perl one too.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen;

my $header = <> . <>;
print $header;

my $last_sequence_number = 0;

open( my $output, ">", "output.$last_sequence_number.out" ) or die $!;
print {$output} $header;
$seen{$last_sequence_number}++;

while (<>) {
    my ($key) = split;
    next unless $key =~ m/^\d+$/;
    my $sequence_number = int( $key / 1000 );
    if ( not $sequence_number == $last_sequence_number ) {
        print "Opening new file for $sequence_number\n";
        close($output);
        open( $output, ">", "output.$sequence_number.out" ) or die $!;
        print {$output} $header unless $seen{$sequence_number}++;
        $last_sequence_number = $sequence_number;
    }
    print {$output} $_;
}
```

What this does is:

- read two lines from your input to figure out the headers.
- run through the rest of the input, extracting the 'number bit'.
- divides it by 1000 to figure out a 'file number' to write to.
- opens a new file for that if it's relevant. (And if it's the first time it's done so, writes some headers).
- prints the current line to the currently open file.

Invoke via either a pipe or `myscript.pl <filename>`

Comment: that is a nice thing...could you tell me how i can provide it wiht multiple input files and the output for the first fiel is something like file 1 to 10 and the next is file 11 to 20 or 24 or somthng?

Comment: Although bear in mind that the 'header' is the firs two lines of the first file in the list. If they're the same that won't matter.

Answer (score 1):

This short Perl program will process a file specified as a parameter on the command line. It pushes onto `@header` any line that doesn't start with a number. Otherwise it divides the number by 1,000 and checks to see if there is already a file open for that millenium. If not tehn it opens a file for output and prints the header lines to it. Then the current line is printed to the selected file handle

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my (@header, @fh);

while ( <> ) {

  if ( /^(\d+)/ ) {

    my $n = int $1 / 1000;

    unless ( $fh[$n] ) {
      my $file = sprintf 'file%d.txt', $n+1;
      open $fh[$n], '>', $file;
      print { $fh[$n] } @header;
    }

    print { $fh[$n] } $_;
  }
  else {
    push @header, $_;
  }
}

close $_ for grep $_, @fh;
```

#### output - file1.txt

```
NAMES   n0  n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6  n7
REGION  chr 1   100000
404 AAAAAAGA
992 TTTTTTTA
```

#### output - file2.txt

```
NAMES   n0  n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6  n7
REGION  chr 1   100000
1146    CCCCGGCC
1727    CCCCCACC
1778    GCCCCCCC
```

Comment: that is a nice thing...could you tell me how i can provide it wiht multiple input files and the output for the first fiel is something like file 1 to 10 and the next is file 11 to 20 or 24 or somthng?

Comment: @ktoui: Now you're changing the requirement! If the numbers are just the first column divided by 1000 then you can just run this program against each file, one at a time

Comment: the answer soes not change the numbers in the REGION line as in th euqestion could tyou have a look please