# How can I have my Perl script read parameters from the command line?

Tags: perl

a parsing script I am using looks like that

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my (@header, @fh);

while ( <> ) {

  if ( /^(\d+)/ ) {

    my $n = int $1 / 1000;

    unless ( $fh[$n] ) {
      my $file = sprintf 'file%d.txt', $n+1;
      open $fh[$n], '>', $file;
      print { $fh[$n] } @header;
    }

    print { $fh[$n] } $_;
  }
  else {
    push @header, $_;
  }
}

close $_ for grep $_, @fh;
```

The file I pass to the script is processed an the output is in file1 file2 ..... how can I modify the scripot that there is an additional paramter to the script with which the output is modified to be file1_1 file1_2... if the additional paramter is 1 if the additional paramter would be 2 it would be file2_1 file2_......

Comment: You have to approach it differently, and not use `while ( <> ) {`

Comment: @ Sobrique oh no...such a sahme..is there any way to make it in your script from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227962/parsing-from-colum-in-perl-or-bash

Comment: Parameters on the command line are given in array `@ARGV`..

Comment: `my $prefix = shift` and then `my $file = sprintf 'file%s_%d.txt', $prefix, $n+1`. Though of course you may want to account for optional prefixes. It could be done more safely by using `Getopt`, or using the `-s` switch (see [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Answer (score 4):

If I were to make a change like that, I would make that parameter optional, so as not to break other dependencies. Since you are already relying on `@ARGV`, that means that we cannot simply `shift` the parameter, or we must make the parameter non-optional.

E.g.:

```
my $prefix = shift;  # non-optional parameter now
...
my $file = sprintf 'file%s_%d.txt', $prefix, $n+1
```

But if this program is then used by someone or something that does not expect that parameter, it will remove a file from the input and break the program.

Instead, you can use the rudimentary switch parsing on the command line with the [`-s`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-s*) switch, or use [`Getopt::Long`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long), which is a popular module for this purpose.

```
perl -s program.pl -prefix=1 input1 input2 ...
```

And then inside the program, either use `our $prefix` or `$main::prefix`, so that you do not get `strict` errors. Then you can also check if `$prefix` is defined, and handle it accordingly. E.g.:

```
if (defined $main::prefix) {
    $main::prefix .= "_";  # append "_"
} else {
    $main::prefix = "";    # empty string
}
my $file = sprintf 'file%s%d.txt', $prefix, $n + 1;
```

Or using [`Getopt::Long`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my $prefix;
GetOptions("prefix=s" => \$xyz);
```

Usage:

```
perl program.pl -prefix=1 input1 input2 ...
```